# Errors when trying sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, updates, libreoffice

I'm trying to install mpich because I want`pip install mpi4py` to work, I'm on ubuntu 16.04 this is the error I get when I run `sudo apt install mpich`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-core (>= 1:5.2~) but 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0 is to be installed
                  Breaks: libreoffice-style-breeze (>= 1:5.2~) but 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0 is to be installed
                  Breaks: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:5.2~) but 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0 is to be installed
                  Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:5.2~) but 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0 is to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:5.3.3~rc2) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-gtk : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-style-breeze : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
 mpich : Depends: hwloc-nox or
              hwloc
     Depends: libmpich12 (= 3.2-6build1) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libcr0 (>= 0.8.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: libmpich-dev (= 3.2-6build1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So then I tried `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-stix libabw-0.1-1v5 libcdr-0.1-1 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2.9.1 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libetonyek-0.1-1 libfreehand-0.1-1 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3
  libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.10-0v5 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libreoffice-gtk librevenge-0.0-0 libsuitesparseconfig4.4.6 libvisio-0.1-1 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3
  libwps-0.4-4 lp-solve
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,377 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 222842 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0) over (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/arrows/A23-CurvedArrow-Gray-Left.svg.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.3.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates, that the required folder is somehow missing. This could be the result of a previous error when installing libreoffice. Try to fix the “sudo apt-get -f install” process by creating the folder manually.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/arrows
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

If there are more of this “operation not permitted”, try also manually creating these folders and repeat the “sudo apt-get -f install” until it succeeds.

Just to be save, reinstall the package after you fixed it:

```
$ apt-get -s install --reinstall libreoffice-common
```